# 'Object.ReferenceEquals' is always false because it is called with a value type

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, slsvcutil

When I use **SlSvcUtil.exe** to create my service client files, I see code like this:

```cs
private string CategoryField;

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string Category
{
    get
    {
        return this.CategoryField;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CategoryField, value) != true))
        {
            this.CategoryField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Category");
        }
    }
}
```

When I inspect it with **ReSharper**, I receive the following warning:

> 'Object.ReferenceEquals' is always false because it is called with a value type

I understand that *[strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106046/682480)*, but I seem to receive this warning for every property.

**ReSharper** recommends the following:

*Note: This includes my custom styling of putting simple getters on one line, inverting the `if`, removing the redundant `object` qualifier and the `!= true` comparison*

```cs
private string CategoryField;

[DataMember]
public string Category
{
    get { return this.CategoryField; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(this.CategoryField, value)) { return; }

        this.CategoryField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Category");
    }
}
```

So it really begs the question, why does **SlSvcUtil.exe** use `ReferenceEquals` instead of `Equals` if `ReferenceEquals` is always going to return false?

Comment: How does the expression `Equals(this.CategoryField, value)` compile? Where is it getting the `Equals()` method? As for the bigger question, it sounds like a ReSharper bug to me. System.String obviously is not a value type and so while it's probably better to use something like `this.CategoryField.Equals(value)` instead of `object.ReferenceEquals()`, the specific complaint Resharper has does not appear to be valid.

Comment: It compiles just fine. It's `Object.Equals()`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I forgot there was the static version of that method. Duh. Anyway, I still think you're looking at a Resharper bug.

Comment: Which very well could be, it's 9.0 EAP, but I did notice that `enum`, `string`, and `struct` objects like `int` and `bool` throw that warning and recommend `Object.Equals()`, but custom classes I've created don't and `Object.ReferenceEquals()` is just fine.

Comment: That's what I mean. The warning is valid for value types like Enums, int and bool, and of course user-defined structs. The warning shouldn't be shown for reference types, including custom classes but also including System.String, which is also a reference type (the immutability is a red herring).

Comment: Agreed it looks like a bug as ReSharper 8.2 doesn't complain. However, I think it should be noted that in almost all cases, `ReferenceEquals` will return false unless the string is interned. `Equals` seems like the proper use.

Comment: So if the warning is valid for those value types, the question of why **SlSvcUtil.exe** doesn't use `Equals` instead of `ReferenceEquals` in those instances still stands it seems.

Comment: Related post - [Comparing boxed value types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6205029/465053) *&* [Equality of two structs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2042282/465053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems debatable whether you would want to use `Equals` or `ReferenceEquals` for strings.  `Equals` will compare the values of the strings, whereas `ReferenceEquals` will compare references -- however, due to string interning, equivalent string literals will come out as the same reference.  For example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = "hi", y = "hi", z = string.Concat('h', 'i');
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x, y));   // true
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x, z));   // false

        Console.WriteLine(Equals(x, y));   // true
        Console.WriteLine(Equals(x, z));   // true

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

So how did the authors of the code generation algorithm decide?  A couple of considerations I can think of:

- Performance: `Object.Equals` requires a virtual method call, which is likely less performant than the static `Object.ReferenceEquals` (given that we are talking about strings, which as reference types do not require boxing).
- *Normally* you would want to use `ReferenceEquals` for reference types -- the authors may have decided that it was not worth maintaining separate code for the special case of strings.
- Note also that using `ReferenceEquals` is the *defensive* choice in this specific instance.  Using `ReferenceEquals` ensures that the setter is applied in case #2 above, whereas using `Equals` would *not* apply the setter in that case.  You could probably dream up some corner case where the latter behavior could introduce a very hard-to-detect bug.

Anyway, the Resharper warning is clearly wrong.  `String` is a reference type, not a value type, and (as demonstrated in the above example) `ReferenceEquals` can in fact return `true` for string values.

Comment: Then to me, there's the whole question of should you use the `Equals()` extensions specific to the object you are comparing instead of `Object.Equals()` or `Object.ReferenceEquals()`.

Comment: @CodeMaverick right -- ideally you would use the type-specific override (or the static version `string.Equals(string, string)`).  But we are talking about auto-generated code, after all ...

Comment: Right ... pertinent to the question, it's auto-generated code, but I was selfishly wanting to know which would be preferred, as not all auto-generated code can or should be considered "best practice."

Comment: Now ... I would like to add, I used string in the example code, but obviously there all sorts of objects where their property setters are exactly the same as the example.

Comment: @CodeMaverick but for the "all sorts of objects", the correct choice would be `ReferenceEquals` if they are reference types, and `Equals` if they are value types... no?  `String` is a singular case due to immutability and interning ...

Comment: Exactly, so to me, I guess the answer is your last bullet point, `Object.ReferenceEquals()` was used as a defensive choice to make sure that the setter is always applied in those value type cases.

Answer (score 1):

@McGarnagle

> however, due to string interning, equivalent string literals will come out as the same reference

strings are not always interned. In order to be interned, the string value needs be known at compile time. I.E only string literals and there concatenations are interned.
Also there is varying interning for different versions / builds of the .NET runtime.
Eric Lippert, who was on the C# compiler team at Microsoft, wrote about this issue, see: ["String interning and String.Empty" Sept 2009](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/)

As for comparing two strings for *value* equality.

`if (String.CompareOrdinal (strA, strB) != 0) ...` is likely the most efficient.

Comment: I think McGarnagle probably knows this, even though they didn't say it explicitly.  The example shown `Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x, z));   // false` demonstrates it.

Comment: In the original poster's example the string value coming in is unknown, concerning its value and its "interned-ness". So ReferenceEquals returns false for many comparisons of equal string values.
And PropertyChanged event should only be called when the property value has actually changed.